# Does jQuery do any initial processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question. If you include jQuery in a page of HTML, is there any initialization overhead before one uses any jQuery functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By virtue of simply including the jQuery script, you do indeed get some overhead. jQuery builds itself up inside an [immediately executed function](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/).

In 1.3.2 the biggest things it does are for IE support:

- creates a temporary `form` element with one `input` element inside it, to check to see if the browser returns elements by name when querying by `getElementById` - [[Source](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src/selector.js#L720)]
- creates a temporary `div` with a empty `comment` node in it, to check to see if the browser returns only elements when doing `getElementsByTagName("*")` - [[Source](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src/selector.js#L749)]
- creates a temporary anchor element, to see if `getAttribute` returns normalized `href` attributes - [[Source](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src/selector.js#L780)]
- creates a temporary `div` with this html in it:

  ```
  '   <link/><table></table><a href="/a" style="color:red;float:left;opacity:.5;">a</a><select><option>text</option></select><object><param/></object>'
  ```

  and proceeds to read off a bunch of characteristics from that structure. This is to build the [`jQuery.support`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support) object that was created in lieu of deprecating `jQuery.browser` - [[Source](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src/support.js)]

It also does some smaller things like:

- creates a whole whack of regular expression objects
- parses `navigator.userAgent` for some deprecated browser sniffing support
- gets the current Date from the system (`+new Date`)

Keep in mind all this barely adds up to any noticeable lag, as others have suggested.

Comment: Yes, feature tests are not very time-consuming, contrary to many beliefs. ~80 more-or-less involved tests in my CFT (http://yura.thinkweb2.com/cft/) only take ~18ms on FF3.5

Comment: @kangax: Holy hell. That is a fantastic reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a tiny bit. On my very fast machine, it seems to delay the page load by about 4ms.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery itself doesn't really do much to speak of at load time, but naturally downloading the script, parsing it and executing the inline code to define all its functions takes a little while. It's unlikely to be terribly significant in itself on a normal desktop browser.